# Understanding bound TypeVars with generic parameters

Tags: python, generics, type-hinting

I'm trying to understand how bound variables work in TypeVars. I understand that any subclass of the bound class is allowed, but once I make the bound class a generic, things that I would expect to work don't:

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

class X:
    pass
class Y(X):
    pass

T = TypeVar("T", bound=X)

class A(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, param: T):
        self.param = param
class B(A[T]):
    pass

S = TypeVar("S", bound=A[X])

def foo(bar: S) -> S:
    return bar

foo(B(Y())) # Type "B[Y]" cannot be assigned to type "A[X]"
```

Could someone explain why this doesn't work, and if any workarounds are known?

Comment: Your program runs for me.

Comment: @Loocid Of course the program runs, but the static type checker Pylance in VSCode raises errors. I assume mypy would as well, but I don't use mypy.

Answer (score 1):

```py
T = TypeVar("T", bound=X, covariant=True)
```

Although `Y` is a subtype of `X`, `T[Y]` is a subtype of `T[X]` iff A is covariant. See [here](https://peps.python.org/pep-0483/#covariance-and-contravariance). By specifying generic type `T` to be covariant, the warning disappears.

I'll try to come back and elaborate more when/if I have time.